# Spring-WS vs JAX-WS

Tags: web-services

Im new to Web Service world and can someone say how different is JAX-WS from Spring-WS and which one to use.

Regds
Laks

Answer (score 1):

Please check answer to other similar questions such as: [Which framework is better CXF or Spring-WS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297033/which-framework-is-better-cxf-or-spring-ws)

Also, in the future might be worth checking existing questions like so :
[https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20spring-ws%20vs%20jax-ws](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com%20spring-ws%20vs%20jax-ws)