# What is purpose of CXF or Spring WS

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to consuming web services. I am trying to consume a SOAP service. This is currently in the test environment. What I have done is

1. Use wsdl2java to generate a wsdl that I have copied to my domain folder.
2. Use the API to send requests and receive responses.

What concerns me is do I need CXF or Spring WS to wire the service or is what I have sufficient. I am asking this because I have seen elsewhere like

What I don't get is where I would generate property when environments are switching from development to QA to production. And do I need to use CXF or Spring WS or are the annotated classes (@WebServiceClient sufficient) to consume the SOAP service. Basically, how to connect to different endpoints.

I apologize if this is rudimentary question. Thanks.

Comment: I think, [that great comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297033/which-framework-is-better-cxf-or-spring-ws/3172171#3172171) will explain to you "who is who".

Answer (score 5):

Spring-WS and Apache CXF are primarily useful for creating web-services. They are alternative web service implementations to the one that ships with Java6.

You *can* use them for writing clients, but there's not really much point, unless you're really keen on the alternative API that those provide.

The standard JAX-WS artifacts generated by `wsdl2java` should be perfectly sufficient for what you need.

As for your second question regarding how to target different prod/QA endpoints, you should ask a separate question for that, with full examples of what you have.