# Soap client framework

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

I have web application on Spring MVC and looking for SOAP consumer - frameworks to be used with Spring MVC. The web app is only the consumer and doesn't host any web service.
Options I am looking for SOAP client are :

```
  1. JAX-WS
  2. Spring MVC & Spring-WS
  3. Apache Axis or CXF
  4. Spring Integration or Camel. Can these be used for consumption of
services too? Won't that be overhead?
```

What do you suggest? Please recommend the best option if also not in the above list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this excellent post about this subject.

[Which framework is better CXF or Spring-WS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297033/which-framework-is-better-cxf-or-spring-ws?rq=1)

My advise based on the fact that you only have to develop one client, is to consider making your choice based on your context to optimize your productivity and avoid adding tones of layer and libs in your app:

1. Pure Java EE app or already using Spring APP
2. Your current Application Server : Jboss for example already provide a CXF implementation that is very suggested to use
3. Service providers "age": I have met some problems in calling AS400 or old IBM system webservices. Any client was not working.
4. Your IDE and Plugins : for example, if you have eclipse, Axis/CXF plugins are very interesting.

Concerning Camel, it is interesting if you have different source and destination like HTTP to JMS.

For Camel, read this post:

[What exactly is Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845186/what-exactly-is-apache-camel)